# Is there a noun for Recalled Item

Tags: single-word-requests

The item being recalled can be *memory*, when using it as *remember*, but there are other contexts as well. I was wondering if there is a more general word, perhaps utilizing the "recall" root.

Comment: From the title, I thought you were referring to Toyotas.  :-)  Can you clarify the other contexts (an example or two)?

Comment: @fixer1234 are the other contexts all that different?

Comment: I'm not understanding the context of the question (the way you want to use recalled).  The term means "brought back".  Memory is an internal mental process.  Bringing back an object is an external physical process.  Recalling a car generally refers to a request to return it rather than the action of bringing it back.  I'm having trouble visualizing how you want to use it.  Can you give an example, maybe a sentence?

Comment: @fixer1234 edited to make this clear. I meant the general meaning of recall, as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The item being recalled is a **recollection** (despite its spelling that looks closer to *collect* that to *recall*.)

[thefreedictionary.com/recollection](http://thefreedictionary.com/recollection)

recollection (ˌrɛkəˈlɛkʃən)
n

1. the act of recalling something from memory; the ability to remember
2. something remembered; a memory